# Update progressbar in Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to update a progressbar in a recyclerview item.
Now I have no idea, how to get the progressbar within an item and update it from another class, which isn't connected in anyway with this adapter.

Here's my code:

```
public class TransmissionAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TransmissionAdapter.ViewHolderUI> {

    public static class ViewHolderUI extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ImageView fileTypeImage;
        TextView fileName;
        TextView progressDescription;
        TextView timeAgoTrans;
        ProgressBar uploadProgess;

        public ViewHolderUI(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            fileTypeImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.file_type_image);
            fileName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.file_name);
            progressDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.progress_description);
            timeAgoTrans = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.time_ago_trans);
            uploadProgess = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar_transmission);
        }

    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolderUI onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view, null);

        return new ViewHolderUI(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolderUI holder, int position) {

        holder.fileName.setText(TransmissionsView.itemTexte.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return TransmissionsView.itemTexte.size();
    }


}
```

I tried to put the progress in an arraylist and update the progress in the recyclerlist using notifyDataSetChanged and set the current progress in "onBindViewHolder" method. But if the progressbar is to fast the UI Thread skipped frames, so is this the right way?!

Comment: When you want to update the progress bar in fact ?

Comment: If you run the app using a share menu, I run a new class, where some files will be uploaded, so I want to show the progress